# I Want To Build Update Form When I Change Main Dropdown Menu Then update the second dropdown list

Tags: php, ajax, html, codeigniter

```
                     <div>
                        <label for="form-field-select-3">State : </label>
                        <br />
                        <select class="chosen-select form-control" id="State" name="State" data-placeholder="Choose a State...">
                            <option value="0"> </option>
                            <?php
                             $query=$this->db->query("select Address_State from ref_address_state  where Address_State_ID='".$property->State_ID."'");
                             $query=$query->row();   
                             foreach($Address_State as $rows)
                             {
                                if($rows['Address_State']==$query->Address_State)
                                   {

                                            echo "<option value='".$rows['Address_State_ID']."' selected>".$rows['Address_State']."</option>";                                                                    
                                  }
                            else
                                  {
                                           echo "<option value='".$rows['Address_State_ID']."'>".$rows['Address_State']."</option>";                                                                    

                                  }
                            }       
                             ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <label for="form-field-select-3">City : </label>
                        <br />
                        <select class="chosen-select form-control" id="City" name="City" data-placeholder="Choose a City...">
                            <option value="0">  </option>
                           <?php
                           $query=$this->db->query("select city_name from ref_city  where city_id='".$property->City."'");
                             $query=$query->row();   
                             foreach($city_name as $rows)
                             {
                                if($rows['city_name']==$query->city_name)
                                   {

                                     echo "<option value='".$rows['city_id']."' selected>".$rows['city_name']."</option>";                                                                    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    echo "<option value='".$rows['city_id']."'>".$rows['city_name']."</option>";                                                                    

                                    }
                             }
                                  ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="form-field-select-3">Locality : </label>
                        <br />
                        <select class="chosen-select form-control" id="Locality" name="Locality" data-placeholder="Choose a Location...">
                            <option value="0">  </option>
                               <?php
                             $query=$this->db->query("select locality_name from ref_locality  where locality_id='".$property->Locality."'");
                             $query=$query->row();   
                             foreach($locality_name as $rows)
                             {
                                if($rows['locality_name']==$query->locality_name)
                                   {

                                     echo "<option value='".$rows['locality_id']."' selected>".$rows['locality_name']."</option>";                                                                    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    echo "<option value='".$rows['locality_id']."'>".$rows['locality_name']."</option>";                                                                    

                                    }
                             }
                                  ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add more detail as to what you would like us to do

Answer (score 1):

I think u want something like this

http://www.91weblessons.com/codeigniter-ajax-country-state-city-drop-down/

javascript:

```
 <script>
    function selectState(country_id)//on change of country select box
    {
      if(country_id!="-1"){
        loadData('state',country_id);
        $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
      }else{
        $("#state_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select state</option>");
        $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
      }
    }

    function selectCity(state_id)//on change of state select box
    {
      if(state_id!="-1"){
       loadData('city',state_id);
      }else{
       $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
      }
    }


    function loadData(loadType,loadId){
      var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
      $("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
      $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).html('Please wait... <img src="image/loading.gif" />');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadData",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
          $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
          $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");
          $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);
        }
     });
    }

    </script>
```

controller:

```
<?php

    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->model('model');
       $result['list']=$this->model->getCountry();
       $this->load->view('top');
       $this->load->view('index',$result);
       $this->load->view('footer');
    }

     public function loadData()
     {
       $loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
       $loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

       $this->load->model('model');
       $result=$this->model->getData($loadType,$loadId);
       $HTML="";

       if($result->num_rows() > 0){
         foreach($result->result() as $list){
           $HTML.="<option value='".$list->id."'>".$list->name."</option>";
         }
       }
       echo $HTML;
     }
    ?>
```

model:

```
<?php
function getCountry()
{
   $this->db->select('id,country_name');
   $this->db->from('country');
   $this->db->order_by('country_name', 'asc');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query;
}

function getData($loadType,$loadId)
{
   if($loadType=="state"){
    $fieldList='id,state_name as name';
    $table='state';
    $fieldName='country_id';
    $orderByField='state_name';
   }else{
    $fieldList='id,city_name as name';
    $table='city';
    $fieldName='state_id';
    $orderByField='city_name';
   }
   $this->db->select($fieldList);
   $this->db->from($table);
   $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
   $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query;
 }

?>
```

Comment: Please add a solution to your post, not just a link, in case the link goes down.

Comment: @Dakkaron actually i was clear about the question that's y i put only link but have edited now

Comment: Whenever you answer something with a link, always include the critical parts of the solution in your answer. Your answer might be on this page for years, but the link might be not. So someone else with the same question might find your post but can't do anything with the answer since the link is broken. Thanks for including the answer, I will upvote now instead of downvote.