# How to write a better method for a drop down list in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a country drop down list in codeigniter project. The following is function for selecting a city from a country chosen by the user.

```
public function select_auth_city($user_country){
        if($user_country=='USA
            $user_country=1;
        }elseif($user_country=='CANADA'){
            $user_country=2;
        }elseif($user_country=='Netherland'){
            $user_country=3;
        }elseif($user_country=='BURMA'){
            $user_country=4;
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('city', array('country_id' => $user_country));
        $query=$query->result_array();
        return $query;

    }
```

Following is the script

```
 <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#user_country').change(function(){
                $('#user_city').html('<option> Fetching...</option>');

                var user_country =$('#user_country').val();

                //alert(new_div);

                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",

                    data:"user_country="+user_country,
                    url:"<?php echo site_url('ajax/select_auth_city/'); ?>",
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(resp){
                        //alert(resp);
                        $('#user_city').html(resp);
                    }
                });
                });
    </script>
```

I have only four option in the country list, but the problem is when selecting towns from the city list, the function in the model shown above is not feasible when implementing it to select towns/villages drop down, since there will be hundred of cities and writing a function similar to the one shown below is not possible

```
public function select_auth_town($user_city){
        if($user_city=='New York'){
            $user_town=1;
             ......
```

I have tried tutorials from the internet but it did not really work for me. How can I implement a function for selecting a selecting dropdown which has so many options to choose from without bulking up my source code.

Comment: After voting it down, your responsibility do not end there, you should at least direct me somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You have to store country table id as value in option tag so that u can fetch data based on that.

eg.

```
 <option value="<?php echo $country['county_id'];?>"><?php echo $country['county_name'];?></option>
```

u can also check my answer in this

[I Want To Build Update Form When I Change Main Dropdown Menu Then update the second dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911402/i-want-to-build-update-form-when-i-change-main-dropdown-menu-then-update-the-sec/30914137#30914137)

Comment: Thanks for the response @mokNathal, My country and city drop down list is working fine, I want to add one more drop down list, which is when choosing a city i get a list of towns, the thing is the method that I use for country and city drop down list is not feasible when it comes to city to town drop down list because of the sheer amount of city list that I have.

Comment: And I did try to implement the solution that you have provided in the link days ago, I wasn't able to integrate them with the code that I have. Ill try once again